# Is it possible to join all objects into one and their animations into one?

Tags: animation, unity

**SITUATION:** I want to create an animated "3D experiment" which will be imported to Unity for Vuforia AR. The animated 3D model will include lots of small 3D objects(10 chemical equipments,...).

**I'VE DONE:** At first, I had them animated in Blender by changing each "equipment's" state, one by one at each keyframe (140 keyframes in total). Then I exported the file to .fbx and put it in Unity.

**I EXPECT:**: The "experiment" had all of its equipment animated, which means there would be only one big model - The "experiment" and its one Animation.

**TURNED OUT:**  each object has their own animation, 10 "equipments" - 10 animations, each lasts 140 keyframes. The inspector only let one animation run at a time.
(I haven't tried but I guess: to make all of them animate in parallel in Unity we have to assign each "chemical equipment" to its according animation, somehow...)

**MY QUESTION** is that: Is It Possible to make all 10 "chemical equipment" as only one big object and all the animations into one animation, so that when animating each "equipment" is just like animating a part of an object and when exporting the file, we will have only: **ONE big model and ONE animation for that model.**

Comment: Depends what type of animation we are talking about. Can you share some screenshots of what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Is possible. Imagine character animation - one object with rig. You can set which bone will control which vertices very easy by vertex group (and vertex paint) Vertex group must have exactly the same name as bone which control vertices in this group.

Comment: Thank you for your time,
glad to see the word "possible" in your answer. I'll give it a try and update the result later. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you have several animations to put in one.

It would use a null object (empty) and link your animations + mesh top.